# Is there a DNS cache file in my debian9?

Tags: debian, dns, cache

No NSCD , BIND9 ,DNSMASQ installed in my debian9.
Can my debian9 store DNS resolve records in the scene.
Is there a DNS cache file in my debian9 ?
chrome is a application soft in os.
`chrome://net-internals/#dns` can get all dns cache stored in chrome.
I want to know if os itself can store DNS cache in some kinds of file ,instead of such application soft as chrome .
Which file contains all dns resolve records for systemd-resolved?

Comment: Just that maintained by any particular application (Chrome and its 1 min max storage, other browsers, etc)

Comment: chrome://net-internals/#dns can get all dns cache stored in chrome.

Comment: I want to know if os itself can store DNS cache in some kinds of file ,instead of such application soft as chrome .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since Debian uses `systemd` and its `systemd-resolved` resolver, which has a cache, as written in its man:

> systemd-resolved is a system service that provides network name resolution to local applications. It implements a caching and validating DNS/DNSSEC stub resolver

Comment: Which file contains all dns resolve records for systemd-resolved?

Comment: I do not know exactly what you want to achieve but I have the strong feeling you are not going to the correct direction. `systemd-resolved` use a cache in RAM. Maybe things are stored on disk, I do not know,  see `/run/systemd/resolve/` maybe to start. You can use `systemd-resolve --flush-caches` if you would like to delete all cached content. But you certainly need to explain in greeter details your true problem.